# How to write JSON out of order--perhaps multiple writers, if so how?

Tags: json.net

Here's my scenario:

I'm flattening and serializing an object graph. The end result is I'm going to collect all the objects of each type into an array for that type, and have serialized one array per type. But I need to serialize *as I traverse the object graph* (the traversal rules are complex and require reflection to read attributes--so multiple traversals of the graph are highly undesirable--and I want to use JSON.Net's traversal so that its attributes can be used to control the traversal as well).

So lets say I have `TypeA` objects and `TypeB` objects, and lets say `TypeA` objects can have a property of type `TypeB`, and a `TypeB` object can have a property of type `TypeA` (not necessarily reciprocal!). And lets say my object graph looks like this:

```
TypeA aInst1 = new TypeA {
    Id = 1,
    MyB = new TypeB {
        Id = 101,
        MyA = new TypeA {
             Id = 2,
             MyB = null
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
{
    typeAs: [
        {
            id: 1,
            myB: 101
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            myB: null
        }
    ],
    typeBs: [
        {
            id: 101,
            myA: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The key here is: as I'm serializing TypeAs (with, say, a `TypeAConverter`) I will add the necessary TypeB objects to a TypeB HashSet to make sure they get serialized (easy)--but I need to do the inverse when going through the TypeBs--but if I do this linearly I will have already serialized the TypeAs, and can't jump backwards to add the newly discovered objects.

Now, I already know I have to deal with a lot of things (traversal depth, multiple passes, getting a reference to the root object to reach the TypeXs HashSets in the first place), most of which I think I've already figured out.

What I'm unsure how to do is how to deal with the out-of-order-ness of the serialization. My plan so far is to spin up multiple `JsonWriters` for each type, and then append their output to the main document/writer with `WriteRaw`. But to do that, I have to narrow myself to `JsonTextWriter`, because the more abstract `JsonWriter` class doesn't seem to have a way to access the serialized output. I'd rather not limit my users from, say, being able to use `BsonWriter`, for instance (if that's even a practical goal…seems like it).

Incidentally, I didn't come up with this format, I'm just trying to implement it--in as general a way as possible.

## Edit

For some additional background, I've got an interface declared (called `IModel`) that the user will use to "mark" any classes that can be specially handled by this serialization library--there is a `ModelConverter` that catches any `IModel` instances to apply these special rules. I also have a root object (class `Payload`) that the user has to use to put their IModel in (and set some optional configuration). The `Payload` object keeps track of the `TypeXs` arrays (in a `Dictionary<Type, ISet<object>>`, to be exact), and I have a `public static Dictionary<System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext, Payload>` that makes it possible to reach back up (using the `serializer.Context` available to the `ModelConverter`), so that's how I'm able to reach back and add these objects after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, my plan of using multiple `JsonTextWriter`s (one per type) worked, though it is a little clumsy, and I'd still rather find a way that didn't lock me into one `JsonWriter` implementation.

Here's the core of my implementation…obviously the whole solution stretches over two `JsonConverters` and several other classes, but this is the bit where I create, track, and use the per-type `JsonTextWriter`s:

```cs
// Handle Appendices
/* This is a bit messy, because we may add items of a given type to the
    * set we are currently processing. Not only is this an issue because you
    * can't modify a set while you're enumerating it (hence why we make a
    * copy first), but we need to catch the newly added objects and process
    * them as well. So, we have to keep making passes until we detect that
    * we haven't added any new objects to any of the appendices.
    */
Dictionary<Type, ISet<object>> 
    processed = new Dictionary<Type,ISet<object>>(), 
    toBeProcessed = new Dictionary<Type,ISet<object>>(); // is this actually necessary?
/* On top of that, we need a new JsonWriter for each appendix--because we
    * may write objects of type A, then while processing type B find that
    * we need to write more objects of type A! So we can't keep appending
    * to the same writer.
    */
/* Oh, and we have to keep a reference to the TextWriter of the JsonWriter
    * because there's no member to get it back out again. ?!?
    * */
Dictionary<Type, KeyValuePair<JsonWriter,StringWriter>> writers = new Dictionary<Type,KeyValuePair<JsonWriter,StringWriter>>();

int numAdditions;
do
{
    numAdditions = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, ISet<object>> apair in payload.Appendices)
    {
        Type type = apair.Key;
        ISet<object> appendix = apair.Value;
        JsonWriter jw;
        if (writers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            jw = writers[type].Key;
        }
        else
        {
            // Setup and start the writer for this type...
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
            writers[type] = new KeyValuePair<JsonWriter, StringWriter>(jw, sw);
            jw.WriteStartArray();
        }

        HashSet<object> tbp;
        if (processed.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            toBeProcessed[type] = tbp = new HashSet<object>(appendix.Except(processed[type]));
        }
        else
        {
            toBeProcessed[type] = tbp = new HashSet<object>(appendix);
            processed[type] = new HashSet<object>();
        }

        if (tbp.Count > 0)
        {
            numAdditions += tbp.Count;
            foreach (object obj in tbp)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(jw, obj); // Note, not writer, but jw--we write each type to its own JsonWriter and combine them later.
            }
            processed[type].UnionWith(tbp);
        }

        //TODO: Add traversal depth limiter!
    }
} while (numAdditions > 0);

if (payload.Appendices.Count > 0)
{
    writer.WritePropertyName("linked");
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    // Okay, we should have captured everything now. Now combine the type writers into the main writer...
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, KeyValuePair<JsonWriter, StringWriter>> apair in writers)
    {
        apair.Value.Key.WriteEnd(); // close off the array
        writer.WritePropertyName(apair.Key.Name);
        writer.WriteRawValue(apair.Value.Value.ToString()); // write the contents of the type JsonWriter's StringWriter to the main JsonWriter
    }

    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

And I know my use of `Dictionary<Type, KeyValuePair<JsonWriter,StringWriter>>` is a nasty hack. If someone can't tell me a way to get the StringWriter back from the JsonWriter, I'll create a struct for the pair or something. I suppose I could create one struct for holding `processed`, `toBeProcessed`, `jsonWriter`, and `textWriter` and put them all in one `Dictionary` keyed by `Type`. Hmm...